# How to escape double quotes in Json using Java Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am not sure how to get rid of double quotes in JSON value.

Here is my Java Servlet code which is passing json to javascript

```
Object discountAmountObj = 0.0;
discountAmountObj = discountamount + "%";   //have to append "%"

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(discountAmountObj);
jsonObject.add("discount", element);
out.print(jsonObject.toString());
```

JSON value is coming as -> **{"discount":"10.0%"}**

I really need value wihtout double quotes -> **{"discount":10.0%}**

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: why do u need that !!

Comment: Change it to {"discount":0.1} instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If discount contains '%' sign, then it has to be a string and be surrounded by quotes. Only numbers are not surrounded by quotes in JSON as explained here : http://www.json.org/.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is that "10.0%" is not a number data type and in JSON it cannot be expressed without being expressed as a string. The smart way to handle this would be to just drop the percentage sign and leave it as 10.0, or if you want to make it more correct, set it to 10.0/100.0 = 0.1 percent